# Spectrum of composition of graphs( lexicographic product)

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory, sp.spectral-theory

I was wondering how to relate the spectra of the composition of two graphs in term of the factors...someone can help me?

Comment: This paper contains some partial results in this area,
and could give some sense of what's known and not known:
Romain Boulet. "Spectral behavior
of some graph and digraph compositions." 2011.
http://upcommons.upc.edu/handle/2099/10370

Answer (score 3):

If graphs $X$ and $Y$ have adjacency matrices $A$ and $B$ respectively, then the composition
of $X$ around $Y$ has adjacency matrix
$$
  A\otimes J + I\otimes B
$$

Assume $B$ is $k$-regular. Then the all-ones vector $\textbf{1}$ is an eigenvector for $B$ with
eigenvalue $k$ and if $x$ is an eigenvector for $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $x\otimes\textbf{1}$
is an eigenvector for the composition with eigenvalue $\lambda|V(Y)| +k$. If $y$ is an eigenvector
for $B$ orthogonal to $\textbf{1}$ with eigenvalue $\mu$, then $x\otimes y$ is an eigenvector
for the composition with eigenvalue $\mu$.

If $B$ is not regular then there is no simple expression for the spectrum; it can be shown that
it is determined by the spectrum of $X$, $Y$ and the complement of $Y$.

Comment: I'm sorry...what do you mean with the notation V(B)?

Comment: @Roberto: I meant $V(Y)$, it's fixed now.

Comment: exactly...how I thought. Now it makes sence.